# How to get tranlationX and translationY from AnimatorListener on animationEnd?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, animator, animatorset

`p0.toString()` method gives:

```
09-11 10:28:19.904 27113-27113/com.android.testapp D/TAG:
onAnimationEnd:AnimatorSet@4a04036{
    translationX:  10.0  1138.7 
    translationY:  300.0  364.0  
}
```

How can I get `translationX` and `translationY` from `p0`?

Answer (score 0):

I think, it was impossible get translationX and translationY from p0:Animator.
So I get it from target view's .x and .y coordinations, so I user ObjectAnimator.